# How to make a colored axis that is hidden by the grid border, stand out in flot

Tags: css, flot

I have this graph with multiple axes.  Note that the "kW" axis is positioned flush with the grid itself, and despite it being colored, you can hardly tell that it is red.

My goal is to make the axis stand out in its assigned color -- how?

[image]

I imagine there may be a way to slightly move the axis away from the grid, but maybe there are other ways to accomplish what I want, such as making the right border of the grid red, or the like.  I will accept any answer that aligns with my goal, as long as the result looks good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved it via

```
 "grid" : {
        borderWidth: {
            top: 0,
            bottom: 1,
            left: 0,
            right: 1
        },
        borderColor: {right: "red"}
}
```

where borderWidth had to be defined for borderColor to be set